# Alekhine Defense Variations

Tags: opening, alekhines-defense, alekhine

I am seeking for a high-level and in-depth discussion of the Alekhine Defense, including variations, mainlines, and sidelines that favors black.

1. e4 Nf6

Comment: https://www.chessable.com/short-sweet-the-alekhine-defense/course/25399/

Comment: Alekhine is not mainstream enough to get such a coverage :(  There are recent books out there, and are good, but none provides ECO-like coverage of all the relevant lines :(

Comment: Can you cite some of these books

Comment: Yes I can: [this one](https://www.newinchess.com/alekhine-defense) was good, as well as [this one](https://www.amazon.com/Play-Alekhine-Defence-Alexei-Kornev/dp/6197188228).